How come when I use "GPU Compute" in Cycles when rendering the entire render changes?
I've recently been looking everywhere as to why this is presenting as it is and I have found 0 solutions. I have a simple grass setup that displays just fine in EEVEE and "Cycles-CPU". As soon as I try to use the "GPU Compute" option, the entire scene goes dark, with odd reflections. Attached below is a before and after, CPU and then GPU Compute.



I apoligize as I did not include my specs. I'm running on a laptop with the Intel-i7 and the RTX 3070.  Also a noticable error with the GPU Compute are these black boxes that are all over the render. Some spaces are a bit brighter, and others you can see just black box outlines.

Hello and welcome. Could it be overlapping vertices? If not please share a minimally reproducible file https://blend-exchange.com

Sorry for wasting your time. It was the texture that was at fault. I tried out a couple more and some of them have this same issue and others work just fine. Pulled from BlenderKit. I am new here so what should be done about this page now?

No worries. You can leave it or even delete it if you want.

@XanderWay Just as tip for the next time: since we cannot always know what exactly is going on and as you discovered it could as well be the textures, it's not a bad idea to share a screenshot of the material nodetree as well, sometimes this can help discover problems because there are some nodes which are only working in Cycles, some just work in EEVEE and other times it might just be an error in how it is set up  in general.

Roughness values < 0 or > 1 can cause this kind of artifacts

Alright, thank you all for your help. It is much appreciated.
